# Class decorator Nestjs modify each method in a class

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want to create a decorator that would get all methods of a class and wrap them with certain functionality, for this example, just logging like this:

```
export function CustDec<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(Target: T) {
  return class extends Target {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      console.log('@--------------------@');
      (Target as any).prototype.alphaMethod = async (args: any[]) => {
        console.log('@-before-@');
        await (Target as any).alphaMethod();
        console.log('@-after-@');
      };
    }
  };
}
```

The problem is when I apply this decorator to my class:

```
import { Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Firewall } from 'src/auth/decorators/firewall.decorator';
import { CustDec } from './feedback.decorator';

@CustDec
@ApiTags('feedback')
@Controller('feedback')
export class FeedbackController {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await this.alphaMethod(); // <--- here
    }, 3000);
  }

  @Firewall()
  @Post('')
  async alphaMethod() { // <-- and here
    return 'some promised result';
  }
}
```

When I try to call `/feedback` endpoint on my controller, I get an error as if `Firewall` and `Post` decorators stopped working after my `CustDec` changed `alphaMethod`. And even if I call `alphaMethod` from inside my FeedbackController constructor method, I get another error:

```
@-before-@
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
TypeError: Target.alphaMethod is not a function
    at FeedbackController.Target.alphaMethod (/home/zagrava/workspace/test-nest/backend/src/feedback/feedback.decorator.ts:8:31)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/zagrava/workspace/test-nest/backend/src/feedback/feedback.controller.ts:12:18)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

How do I make my CustDec properly wrap all methods of a class with logging?

Answer (score 0):

A class decorator can be implemented like below :

```
function intercept<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(target: T) {
  const methods = getMethods(target.prototype);
  for (const method of methods) {
    const currentMethod = target.prototype[method]
    target.prototype[method] = async (...args: any[]) => {
      console.log("intercepted", new Date());
      const result = currentMethod(args)
      if (result instanceof Promise) {
        await result
      }
      console.log("executed", new Date());
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to get all the functions of the class (except the constructor itself) and wrap them within your custom-defined function.
A helper method to get functions of a class like the below is useful for this scenario :

```
const getMethods = (obj: any) => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(item => typeof obj[item] === 'function' && item !== "constructor")
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFGMHsDsGcBcAEBzApvAsugFpAJrIgLyIAUkARgFYBciAhtAJ4CUxAfIgPLWrjwA6NPC4B3aAAUATpAAOqKfCYA5egFtUsctRYCAZgEsANvAWkDptR0RL5kPYkpUA2hdRqAusSIkA5HoBXaH4DGF9EADIIxDcrAEIfRAAiKDh4KQD+SCkkllBQAAEDaFMpcFRZeAgjelhCADFUVDwKenAAawBhGHTIIyMFRABvUEREVIQMrKlSNhGQMbHYdAAVAw1IAPhSWqZgsjYiTnnFxfpRegsbbANYAXojWWx6LHhcPFmAbkQAeh-EAA8AFoQYhsApUKNFgBfAA0iAAzAAGFEsT5Q6H5BaIWQBChGAzgBiwPZEh5PF44fCzYa-f7AoEMaB4MEQqFjKToAJSaCIaCoUSIaSQNS3VAAybFZDsUhSazLeBrDZbUg0o6IGa+WAi1A4mSi5YszmwAImXwseEARhRSJYeWxmJAjtAgWC8FCvOKpXKlQBK0QqAAHqZmYQhnyBaQBNH6FJkLA6IwmM4PCw6ENoYhoTL4LHhHQVnMoRMkBo3vhCCRhK93lpc3H0AJZDJ4JBbKg0VC9NkyCXEGX3o4HAOK0XsWM++BuZySjX8MQbHnG82222mPJnCO8B52YuG4IV6325uqduF7t9lGY3GE0zk6nrCdTuMYNqBgIjJBkKQkl6FD7TDwJJ4X5QUABF6FMWZO3HRY+2NU0kBIKcpBnTBTx2G97WfGIHFlTREJiNJGHKewhX1MUxxwsZzkuJAEJMXcxkdHCJj6VAPy-H8gz4LZmmAiNwMg1BoPRWCOS5HkNQIkwxNOFis1AZ0QEndIjAXUDEEaZpWg6boShkfozBg0AdhJS9DmOYtXyQSYVk0JCGAuK5+CkIx7keZ45w+GCJ1fdjOO-JIGKQW5EFEbJ2ilAS7Ic+1oRYL4sSxIAA)

[Multiple decorators in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFGMHsDsGcBcAEBzApvAsugFpAJrIgLyIAUkARgFYBciAhtAJ4A0i49ANp6gE50JeAS2jIAlMQB8iAN6hQidjASIADr0iq+8JgDl6AW1SESAeWqpw8AHRp4pgO7QAChq28d+o7HLUxAbgVEXnQAV15oNTdtPUNjawAzIU54PlIhVIMpRB0tSATESioAbQzUAwBdYiISAHIE0OgrIRhaxAAydsQyrIBCGsQAIig4eF5Qq0heQYDQAF95EAABEVTecFRVeFAlxkh4bD4dvYO+ACYITnpYQgAxVFQ8CnpwAGsAYRgxyG4+WSCRoIJvApqQJHIQIpFLB0AAVIRGSCheCka5MJpkCREaQQqFQ+gOegZHLYISwaxcVTYehYA74MH+RAAeiZiAAPABaLmIQ4hIKKOZsADMAAYxbNIYgFmBJapQhROEJwAxYOjlZTqbTcHgwbJmazORyGNA8Dy+Kh+cEwhFENBUA5EK5IAYyag2YIRMhJKReNkYfB4YjkaRddjgqRarBnagos7XaaQrBQilamI2ABGMUisRiILSoJyhVKxAGejIJVa+ngy0heDhSIAFjOgUl0vzIAaTXgLUiqz4Gy2bNhiFQAA9UibCDJbfbSNZ5-ReMhYHRGExihUxHQZHMpd74Iu7HRYdXJYCfqhrJxIMhSIM++tNvAZi3FKpNMn6KlKwRSAel+gbD3tAawDs+Ertp2zQwMa+y8kOI7jqgk56naDhzguS4rsa66btuu5zPuh7oMep6KOePBXjed4nLyL4Fh+Vzfjg+A+P+dhAbRfD0SAkGNNBkRcbwZwIWOE4EKhs7zhSWGrswG5brIBFEQB8Ckf8Z7KBeVG3oMQlnDxb6MV+qA-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-LwDIQGMnDWKW5bgD+5cyqiqqTfNttvUggiwsYX0MISxKZ1XGo0gDL3xwTgyY0gZKIA4UyvJ6gxy2MXcIMDcxiA3acgEAA)

Comment: Thanks, the error with constructor is fixed, but I still get the error with controller. I am not able to call my controller endpoint, because seems like Firewall and Post decorators stop working.

Comment: @RuslanPlastun see the updated answer. Probably wrapping the controller class broke it. Decorators like `@Firewall ` and ``@Post` might use similar methods.