# Add decorator to run personalized code before typeorm Repository methods execution

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator, typeorm, typescript-decorator

In NestJS I'm trying to run personalized code before the execution of the **Repository** class methods provided by typeorm.

This is my situation in my file person.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class Person {
    constructor(
       @InjectRepository(Person)
       @PersonalizedDecorator() // is this the right way?
       private readonly personRepository: Repository<Person>
    )
...
```

I added the decorator **PersonalizedDecorator** to try to intercept the Repository class methods but it's not working, the decorator is ignored.

For example when I call personRepository.save(personObj) I would love to always execute some code to automatically format the phone number assigned to a person.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73009667/class-decorator-nestjs-modify-each-method-in-a-class) but the solution here is to add the decorator where the class is declared (in my case where the class Repository is declared) so this solution is not maintainable because I'll have to keep my file updated every time that there is a change in typeorm.

My idea, if possible, would be to have a file where I declare the logic of my decorator and then I can easily inject it where needed

Comment: I'm not experienced with Nest.js but I am very experienced with decorators. If you want to intercept the repository when the constructor is called, that's not possible. TS decorators can only "observe that a parameter has been declared on a method", but doesn't have access to the value of the param when the method is called.

Basically, what you want to do is not possible due to a limitation of TS decorators.
TS Docs regarding this I would recommend you look at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators

Comment: @LearnforFun

Thanks for the answer! 
If you have time I have a follow up question: do you have any suggestion on what could be the best and cleanest solution for me to implement this feature then? 
Eg: extend the repository class or any other idea?

Comment: Well again I'm not very experienced with Nest. But if you're willing to use an intercept function, then instead of using a decorator like the solution it mentioned, you could just directly mutate the Repository class. `import { Repository } from "typeorm"`, then `const tmpSave = Repository.prototype.save; Repository.prototype.save = function(...args: any[]) { /* some logic */ tmpSave.call(this, ...args) }`